# Javascript Freecodecamp "Do not use a Boolean as a Constructor"

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop

I have a small problem when I started the "Falsy Bouncer" challenge on free code camp. When I try to create a new Boolean object like below:

```
var bool = new Boolean();
```

a yellow triangle appears and says "Do not use Boolean as a constructor".

I could easily go around this and not use the object, or use different methods like it says in the Boolean Object documentation and the challenge is not really difficult but I just don't know why I  cannot create a new object inside the Freecodecamp code window? It does this outside or inside the function and with or whithout any parameters.

Does any one know why this happens?

Comment: In what situation would you ever prefer `new Boolean` over simply `true` anyway…?

Comment: Google knows: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: @deceze It is useful for testing certain condition which saves a bit of code, read the documentation as above

Answer (score 5):

[from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) ~

> Do not use a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object to convert a non-boolean value to a
>   boolean value. Instead, use Boolean as a function to perform this
>   task:

```
var x = Boolean(expression);     // preferred 
var x = new Boolean(expression); // don't use
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation you've quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Its because

```js
var boolean = new Boolean(true);
console.log(boolean === true);
```

is `false`.

and

```js
var boolean = new Boolean(false);
console.log(!!boolean);
```

is truthy.

Comment: I am not asking how to use this object as I know that, I am asking why do I get the Yellow triangle saying "Do not use Boolean as a constructor". I want to know why is this appearing?

Comment: @RobertMazurowski because its ill advised for the reasons above.

Comment: So this means the yellow triangle will not break running the code?

Comment: @RobertMazurowski nope its just warning of you of potential problems to come.

Comment: This object is often used to test for False values hence this is the way it works so why would it be ill advised?

Comment: to check for false values just use `!`

Comment: For the falsy bouncer task using this object will save a lot of ifs or switches, the purpose is to return true if you meet any of falsy values like Undefined or Nan in an array and this object returns true if it finds any of these values, this is what it been made for.